# How can I to read a XML from a URL using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have xml file in url :

```
<response>
<sum>0</sum>
<result>0</result>
<comment>sel*1.9488|buy*1.9453</comment>
</response>
```

Now want stored procedure where i can parse this xml file from url and update into columns values which is in `<comment>sel*1.9488|buy*1.9453</comment>` want add **buy*1.9453** to my table. How do it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the XML from a URL you need to do the following:

**Enable [Ole Automation Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191188.aspx)**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Then to get the XML from a url, (answer based on an updated version from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac224833-1ffa-4008-880c-ce8f4d442110/trying-to-obtain-xml-data-from-url-via-sql)), the following creates a temp table to store the value so you can then process the results using an xpath and substring.

This is a working example using a google maps xml, you will need to update the url and xpath to your specific requirements.

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml
CREATE TABLE #xml ( yourXML XML )
GO

DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 

DECLARE @QS varchar(50)

-- & or ? depending if there are other query strings
-- Use this for when there is other query strings:
SELECT @QS = '&date='+convert(varchar(25),getdate(),126)
-- Use this for when there is NO other query strings:
-- SELECT @QS = '?date='+convert(varchar(25),getdate(),126)
SELECT @URL = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=10.247087,-65.598409&sensor=false'  + @QS

DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 

INSERT #xml ( yourXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 

SELECT  yourXML.value('(//GeocodeResponse/status)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') from #xml
```

In order to insert the substring you will need to do something like this to return everything after the pipe and add into your table:

```
INSERT tableDestination (valueDestination)
SELECT  substring(yourXML.value('(//response/comment)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),charindex('|',yourXML.value('(//response/comment)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1)+1,len(yourXML.value('(//response/comment)','VARCHAR(MAX)'))) from #xml
```

Comment: OK, updated the answer to include the substring part to get everything after the pipe.

Comment: @Mattew Warman I write my url into @url and change `SELECT  yourXML.value('(//GeocodeResponse/status)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') from #xml` to `SELECT  yourXML.value('(//response/comment)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') from #xml` ,when i exec procedur select write Acces denied

Comment: Can access the URL via IE on the SQL server you are running the code on? Might have to update `'MSXML2.XMLHttp'` to `'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0'` as the error sounds similar to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1abda1ce-e23c-4d0e-bccd-a323aa7f2ea5/access-is-denied-while-using-microsoftxmlhttp-to-get-a-url-link-in-vbscript-help)

Comment: You might also have to add the url to trust list on the server, read through the posted link above to see how they solved it, let me know how it goes and i will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mattew Warman Hi Mattew , have one question . XML file in url updated an now is `<comment>sel*1.9588|buy*1.9653</comment>` but my procedure parse old comment in XML. Why its not refresh in procedure ?

Comment: @GeoVIP looks like there's a caching problem, [this](http://vbcity.com/forums/p/89622/374522.aspx#374522) post might be helpful, There's two options have a look at IE settings, or add a random value to the query string of the url. I've updated the above code to add date to query string. Does that fix it?

Comment: @GeoVIP: i am new to this xml file in urlthrough SQL..  my scenario is similar to you.. but only difference is that, i want retrieve all the values in XML.. how did you achieve it.. if possible could you send me the substring part alone

Answer (score 2):

How about somethine like

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<response>
<sum>0</sum>
<result>0</result>
<comment>sel*1.9488|buy*1.9453</comment>
</response>'

SELECT  @xml.value('(//response/comment)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

From [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

> Performs an XQuery against the XML and returns a value of SQL type.
>   This method returns a scalar value.
>
> You typically use this method to extract a value from an XML instance
>   stored in an xml type column, parameter, or variable. In this way, you
>   can specify SELECT queries that combine or compare XML data with data
>   in non-XML columns.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18145)

Comment: thank you it works , but i want parse it from url , for example : http://mywebserver/libreria.xml , how do it ?