# How to read XML file from URL in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I would like to read an xml and get a value from it but the xml file is returned via the following url:

```
http://webserver/XMLResult
```

I try To read the xml file, I used the folowing code :

```
    INSERT INTO T(XmlCol)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ‘http://webserver/XMLResult’,SINGLE_BLOB) as c
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file… could not be opened. Operating
>   system error code 123(error not found).

Do you know how to fix this issue?

If it is not possible, can someone recommend the best method which is help me reed XML from URL in sql server 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I to read a XML from a URL using T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `data-file` parameter of the `OPENROWSET` function can't point to an URL. I would suggest to read the XML data *outside* of the TSQL block, possibly passing the data as a parameter to a stored procedure.
If this is not possible and you *must* read the XML data from within TSQL, then two options come to my mind, although I am not a big fan of neither of them:

- use a CLR function and read your XML data from there;
- try to exploit the COM objects available to SQL Server machine by way of the `sp_OACreate` system stored procedure, as suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6856df2b-93f9-4e54-bd15-25acf0b00124/reading-an-url-data?forum=transactsql).