# Need to convert XML online Document into SQL-Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

http://www.greaterkashmir.com/feed.aspx?cat_id=2

the above is Online link of xml RSS newsFeed  document.
i need to retrieve that and convert each data item in SQL Table.

**the kind of solution i am looking is below. in it there is a issue it return NULL**

[How can I to read a XML from a URL using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

1.Save the `aspx` page as a `xml` document.( I have saved it as `check.xml`)

2.Create a `table` to store XML data as below,

```
 CREATE TABLE xmlinput
 (
  Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  XMLData XML,
  createdate DATETIME
  )
```

3.Insert `xmlinput` table from the `xml` file using `OPENROWSET` as below,

```
 INSERT INTO xmlinput(XMLData, createdate)
 SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\DEVSQL2012\SQLServer\check.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

4.Now we have to use `sp_xml_preparedocument` stored procedure (with `OPENXML`   function  ) to process
   the xml data stored in `Xmlinput` table.

```
 DECLARE @XML AS XML, @doc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

 SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM xmlinput
 --select @XML

 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @XML


 SELECT Category, link, title,description,  pubDate ,guid
 into xmldata

 FROM OPENXML(@doc, 'xml/channel/item')
 WITH 
(
Category [varchar](50)          'category',
link [varchar](100)             'link',
title [varchar](100)            'title',
description [varchar](1000)     'description',
pubDate [varchar](100)          'pubDate',
guid    [varchar](100)          'guid'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @doc  --Call this sp to remove document cache
GO


select *from xmldata
```

Comment: i cannot store store file 
i have many RSS links where from i get the DATA in XML format

Comment: so i need same kind of solution but Local path must be replace with Online.  like i mentioned above of the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql

Comment: check above Link @bmsqldev