# TSQL-failing to parse XML(namespaces)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Here is a my SQL:

```
    create table sqm (data xml)    
    insert into sqm
    select '<DataSet xmlns="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd nbrfxrates.xsd">
            <Cube date="2017-06-30">
                <Rate currency="AED">1.0867</Rate>
                <Rate currency="AUD">3.0665</Rate>
                <Rate currency="BGN">2.3284</Rate>
            </Cube>
            </DataSet>'

    select
    m.c.value('@date', 'date') as valuta
    from sqm as s
    outer apply s.data.nodes('/DataSet/Body/Cube') as m(c)
```

After spending hours trying to find out why my SQL kept returning NULL in the db, I discovered that my problem was due to Hyperlink references at the very beginning of the XML(after DataSet). 
I really want to know why is this happening and who can I delete everything between `<DataSet` end `>`. Is there any other option?

if you can think of a better title, please edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the namespace using [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces)

Also your example XML has no `Body` element so I removed that from the Xpath.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WWKYX52575)

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.bnr.ro/xsd')  

select
m.c.value('@date', 'date') as valuta
from sqm as s
outer apply s.data.nodes('/DataSet/Cube') as m(c)
```

Or alternatively you can use

```
select
m.c.value('@date', 'date') as valuta
from sqm as s
outer apply s.data.nodes('/*:DataSet/*:Cube') as m(c)
```

Comment: I see, but where should the namespace be put when i parse an xml from URL like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @s.dragos It needs to be part of the same statement that uses the Xpath