# Download XML to SQL Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

An XML file is published weekly and I wish to store this to a table (effectively creating a backup and audit log) via a stored procedure call.

I have seen a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql) solution but this doesnt seem to work when specifying the XML file directly, eg http://www.website.com/File.xml

Suggestions welcome!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Don't abuse your database server that way. Downloading files from the internet is something client software should be doing (like a PowerShell script). This is far easier to troubleshoot and monitor as well.

Comment: I should add that i have also tried to use OPENROWSET but this results in an error, Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Cannot bulk load because the file "http://www.website.com/File.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).

Comment: I guess lack of experience in anything else is making me look for a solution this way. The database will be a management database, on a local environment and never in a production setting. The XML will include data used to manage database backups - eg, the XML will include a list of references that will be used for a naming convention. I don't suppose it matters how i get the XML in to the database though, so if there is a better/easier way then i'll take it!

Answer (score 2):

Jeroen's comment was my answer, but i cant mark it as it's a reply.

I opted to still execute the powershell command through SQL since its part of a larger process but could do so with one line of code;

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.website.com/File.xml" -OutFile "C:\temp\File.xml"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got your XML file into a variable yet, but just in case...

```
Declare @XML xml; 
Select @XML = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\File.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 
Select @XML
```

Comment: Yep, that works a treat when the file is available locally, just couldn't implement that directly from a HTTP call. Thanks John :)